# How to abort a workflow transition in Plone

Tags: python, workflow, plone

I am working on a complex validation in a dexterity content type which should check the dependencies across several fields at the workflow transition time - I want it to work in the SimplePublicationWorkflow being triggered when the content is sent from "private" to "pending".

I've registered an event listener for IBeforeEvent and hooked it up - but nothing done there short of raising an exception can stop the transition from happening. (and if you raise an exception there, it goes uncaught and the user sees an error page instead of a custom message).

So, what is the recommended way to validate a transition in modern Plone? I've came across documentation suggesting adding External methods to be called on the Guard expression of the transition - but I would not like to use external methods, and if possible, I'd like to keep the default workflow. Creating a custom one is an option provided a clean way to do the check.

Comment: Mmmm. Maybe the trick is that not allow the transition in the first place instead of aborting it? Maybe set a permission on the content item when the content item is being edited and then tie the workflow transition to permission?

Comment: Relates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440066/plone-workflow-publish-an-object-and-all-used-refered-objects-as-well/38501260#38501260

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to set a *guard* instead.

The guard expression *should* be able to look up a view to facilitate more complex guard code, but when a guard returns `False` the transition isn't even listed as available.

Comment: Not being listed is bad - (as the validation code sets messages on what is  wrong/missing) - I am thinking along of marking the object (with an annotation) on IBeforeTransition so that IAfterTranstion triggers another transition, effectively reverting the first. What would you say?

Comment: Sounds elaborate and hacky to me. :-)

Comment: you could use the guard and add an IStatusmessage to the item's default view that exlpains why the transition is not available (maybe adding the message in the guard's view-code also works)

Comment: @jsbueno For realizing fRiSi's suggestion, have a look at `switchState()' of https://github.com/ida/adi.devgen/blob/master/adi/devgen/helpers/workflow.py It regards all possible failing-cases and prompts errors as UI-msg.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record; I found another use case for this today and I monkey patched [Products.DCWorkflow](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.DCWorkflow/blob/2.2/Products/DCWorkflow/DCWorkflow.py#L263-L282) as a proof-of-concept:

**configure.zcml**

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:monkey="http://namespaces.plone.org/monkey">

  <monkey:patch
      description="Allow aborting workflow transitions"
      class="Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflowDefinition"
      original="doActionFor"
      replacement=".patches.doActionFor"
      />

  <subscriber
      for="Products.DCWorkflow.interfaces.IBeforeTransitionEvent"
      handler=".subscribers.validate_workflow_transition"
      />

</configure>
```

**subscribers.py**

```py
def validate_workflow_transition(event):
    if not check_something():
        raise MyException
```

**patches.py**

```py
def doActionFor(self, ob, action, comment='', **kw):
    ...
    # XXX: above this everything is included without any changes
    #      monkey patch replaces only the last line
    try:
        self._changeStateOf(ob, tdef, kw)
    except MyException:
        # do something
        pass
```

The proof-of-concept worked as expected but I was not satisfied with the ending UI, so I decided to follow Martijn's advice and re-implement everything as a guard; it will need additional code to set the guard on all workflow transitions involved (and remove them on uninstall), and a browser view and viewlet to display a message explaining why the transition is not available, but it will be cleaner at the end.