# Plone workflow: Publish an object, and all used/referred objects as well

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone site with Archetypes objects which refer to other objects (by UID).  When, say, a `news` object is published, all `image` objects which are referred in the `text` attribute, should automatically be published, too.

There are three different kinds of publication - "for all" (visible for anyone), "visible" (for authenticated users), and "restricted" (for members of certain groups).  Which one of these is chosen (in the first place) is determined from the type of the objects. The user only "approves" the object, and the kind of publication is chosen automatically.

To achieve this, I have a `changestate` browser: It extracts the UIDs of all used objects from the `text/html` fields and applies the appropriate workflow transitions to them.

This has worked for some years but doesn't work anymore;
perhaps because of some transaction problems?

However, perhaps my current solution is far too complicated.

It should be a quite common situation: When a "news" is published, all "page requisites" of it *(which are only referred, rather than contained, since any image might be used by more than one news object)* should be published as well.  There must be some "standard solution", right?

If there is no "standard" or "best practice" solution yet, I'm interested in possible transaction gotchas etc. as well.

Comment: There is no solution for this out of the box. First of all: how do you handle a case where an image is referenced by two news with different workflow state?
Apart of that: if you are using a modern Plone you don't need to manually extract items from the body, there's an automatic relation from documents with internal links to other items (the same machinery that alert you when you deleted contents referenced somewhere else).
Please see the `LinkedBy` or `ReferencedImage` in the `reference_catalog` tool

Comment: This case of the two news with differing workflow states is important, of course. My idea would be, the referenced image would need to get the "most public" of the used workflow states; perhaps using differently named "up" and "down" transitions, e.g. `make_visible` vs. `backto_visible`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're sure, that implicitly publishing references doesn't lead to unintended results (imagine an editor go like: "I'd put this in draft-state and decorated it with confidential comments, meant to be temporary until ready for publication, who the heck published this?") and that all content-types have a workflow assigned, the code below is a realization of the algorithm you describe.

In case you have content-type-items which don't have a workflow assigned, an implicit publication would be necessary on the next upper parent with a workflow assigned. But that also changes the inherited permissions of the item's siblings or even cousins and aunts, if the first parent also doesn't have a workflow assigned. However, you could do that, search for "ruthless" in the code and follow the comment's instruction, in that case, but assigning a workflow to all content-types seems more recommendable, here.

To regard back-references, when changing a referenced item to a lower public state than the current state, the user will be informed with a warning that it might not be accessible anymore to the audience of the referencing item, thus an automatic "down-publishing" isn't desirable, as Luca Fabbri points out.

The definition of which state is considered to be more public than another, lives in `PublicRank.states`, you'd need to adjust that to the states of the workflow(s) you use.

Ok, so it's about two files involved, first register two event-handlers in `your.addon/your/addon/configure.zcml`:

```
  <!--  A state has changed, execute 'publishReferences': -->
  <subscriber for="Products.CMFCore.interfaces.IContentish
                   Products.CMFCore.interfaces.IActionSucceededEvent"
          handler=".subscriber.publishReferences" />

  <!--  A state is about to be changed, execute 'warnAbout...': -->
  <subscriber for="Products.CMFCore.interfaces.IContentish
                   Products.DCWorkflow.interfaces.IBeforeTransitionEvent"
          handler=".subscriber.warnAboutPossiblyInaccessibleBackReferences" />
```

And then add `your.addon/your/addon/subscriber.py` with the following content:

```
from Products.statusmessages.interfaces import IStatusMessage
from zope.globalrequest import getRequest


class PublicRank:
    """
    Define which state is to be considered more public than another,
    most public first. Assume for now, only Plone's default workflow
    'simple_publication_workflow' is used in the portal.
    """
    states = ['published', 'pending', 'private']

def isMorePublic(state_one, state_two):
    """
    Check if state_one has a lesser index in the rank than state_two.
    """
    states = PublicRank.states
    if states.index(state_one) < states.index(state_two): return True
    else: return False

def getState(obj):
    """
    Return workflow-state-id or None, if no workflow is assigned.
    Show possible error on the console and log it.
    """
    if hasWorkflow(obj):
        try: return obj.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(obj, 'review_state')
        except ExceptionError as err: obj.plone_log(err)
    else: return None

def getTransitions(obj):
    """
    Return the identifiers of the available transitions as a list.
    """
    transitions = []
    trans_dicts = obj.portal_workflow.getTransitionsFor(obj)
    for trans_dict in trans_dicts:
        transitions.append(trans_dict['id'])
    return transitions

def hasWorkflow(obj):
    """
    Return boolean, indicating whether obj has a workflow assigned, or not.
    """
    return len(obj.portal_workflow.getWorkflowsFor(obj)) > 0

def hasTransition(obj, transition):
    if transition in getTransitions(obj): return True
    else: return False

def isSite(obj):
    return len(obj.getPhysicalPath()) == 2

def publishReferences(obj, eve, RUHTLESS=False):
    """
    If an obj gets published, publish its references, too.
    If an item doesn't have a workflow assigned and RUHTLESS
    is passed to be True, publish next upper parent with a workflow.
    """
    states = PublicRank.states
    state = getState(obj)
    transition = eve.action

    if state in states:
        refs = obj.getRefs()
        for ref in refs:
            ref_state = getState(ref)
            if ref_state:
                if isMorePublic(state, ref_state):
                    setState(ref, transition)
            else: # no workflow assigned
                if RUTHLESS:
                    setStateRelentlessly(ref, transition)

def setState(obj, transition):
    """
    Execute transition, return possible error as an UI-message,
    instead of consuming the whole content-area with a raised Exeption.
    """
    path = '/'.join(obj.getPhysicalPath())
    messages = IStatusMessage(getRequest())
    if hasWorkflow(obj):
        if hasTransition(obj, transition):
            try:
                obj.portal_workflow.doActionFor(obj, transition)
            except Exception as error:
                messages.add(error, type=u'error')
        else:
            message = 'The transition "%s" is not available for "%s".'\
                       % (transition, path)
            messages.add(message, type=u'warning')
    else:
        message = 'No workflow retrievable for "%s".' % path
        messages.add(message, type=u'warning')

def setStateRelentlessly(obj, transition):
    """
    If obj has no workflow, change state of next
    upper parent which has a workflow, instead.
    """
    while not getState(obj, state):
        obj = obj.getParentNode()
        if isSite(obj): break
    setState(obj, transition)

def warnAboutPossiblyInaccessibleBackReferences(obj, eve):
    """
    If an obj is about to switch to a lesser public state than it
    has and is referenced of other item(s), show a warning message
    with the URL(s) of the referencing item(s), so the user can check,
    if the link is still accessible for the intended audience.
    """
    states = PublicRank.states
    item_path = '/'.join(obj.getPhysicalPath())[2:]
    target_state = str(eve.new_state).split(' ')[-1][:-1]
    refs = obj.getBackReferences()

    for ref in refs:
        ref_state = getState(ref)
        if isMorePublic(ref_state, target_state):
            ref_path = '/'.join(ref.getPhysicalPath())[2:]
            messages = IStatusMessage(getRequest())
            message = u'This item "%s" is now in a less published state than \
            item "%s" of which it is referenced by. You might want to check, \
            if this item can still be accessed by the intended audience.' \
            % (item_path, ref_path)
            messages.add(message, type=u'warning')
```

Comment: Of course it will depend on the site and it's audience; in my case I'm pretty sure that it is the desired behaviour to publish all used objects (more precisely, it's a requirement).

Comment: The most important part for me is the `subscriber` mechanism. Thanks for working this out; it looks like a good starting point to me.

For a more general solution, I'd use some dictionary to map ranks to numbers, and have the `isMorePublic` function as a method of the mapping class.

Comment: `isMorePublic`, `publishReferences` and `warnAbout...` should probably better live inside of the class, the other methods are more general wf-related helper-methods. Curious to see, which way you end up taking!

Comment: The problem with a trigger mechanism is **recursion**: a referenced object might be referencing more, and the user most likely would not want this cascade flow unlimitedly. Thus, I might end in using a special workflow form view which lists the _immediate_ references and allows their selection for being co-published

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. It should actually also be possible to compute the "publicness"-comparison of states, instead of manually hardcoding it. BTW, your question would be an ideal candidate for the new docu-platform, as it comes up all the time and led to the compromise, to not assign workflows to Images and Files by default. Maybe you wanna chip in your vote? I'm certainly eager to test, if it could lead to collectively find best-practices: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/plone

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in the end:

I refactored my workflow as follows:

- It doesn't choose transitions automatically anymore (for publication levels) but lets the user explicitly specify `for all`, `visible` or `restricted`.
- I added transitions to switch publication levels (for cases of mistakes).
- These transitions are named differently depending on the direction; e.g., to switch a `restricted` item to `visible`, `make_visible` is used, while the transition to make a `published` item `visible` is called `make_visible_again`. This way, refered items will be affected in the right direction only (not perfect but an improvement).

The problem with non-working publications of refered objects was caused by transactions; moving those from `/temp/` to their public location had involved `transaction.commit()` as well.

Finally, a little gotcha: If a workflow is switched, all review states are initialized anew - it doesn't matter that both the variable name and the states remained unchanged.  Thus, it doesn't work to rename the workflow at this occasion. The original workflow states can be restored by switching back to the old workflow (with the same name but updated functionality).